# Changing WrapGrid's maximumRowsOrColums value by visualState triggers doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, universal, visualstates

I'm making adaptive layout to my win 10 universal application. For some reason when I try to change wrapGrid's maximumRowsOrColumns value in visualState triggers, it doesn't work correctly.

Well it actually works if user changes the windows size, but when launching program, it seems that adaptiveTrigger has no effect to that value.

Here's some code:

```
<Hub>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="WrapPanel.MaximumRowsOrColumns" Value="3" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="WrapPanel.MaximumRowsOrColumns" Value="2" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <HubSection>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                                  x:Name="WrapPanel"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Red" Margin="6" />
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Yellow" Margin="6" />
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Green" Margin="6" />
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Margin="6" />
                </GridViewItem>
            </GridView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the trigger to work at launch you can try forcing the app to launch with a specific width and height. That way your visual states can be triggered. Below is a snippet you would need to put in the yourfile.xaml.cs:

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode != ApplicationViewWindowingMode.Auto;
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Width = 600, Height = 500 };
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

Also a good coding practice is to take out your Visual State Manager XAML from your < Hub >< /Hub> Tags and place them at the end of your code (but inside the < Grid> < /Grid> tag)

```
    <Hub>
        <HubSection x:Name="HubSection" Header="Test">
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                              x:Name="WrapPanel1" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <GridViewItem >
                        <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Red" Margin="6" />
                    </GridViewItem>
                    <GridViewItem>
                        <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Yellow" Margin="6" />
                    </GridViewItem>
                    <GridViewItem>
                        <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Green" Margin="6" />
                    </GridViewItem>
                    <GridViewItem>
                        <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Margin="6" />
                    </GridViewItem>
                    <GridViewItem>
                        <Rectangle Width="250" Height="100" Fill="Orange" Margin="6" />
                    </GridViewItem>
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="wideView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="700" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="WrapPanel1.MaximumRowsOrColumns" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Target="HubSection.Header" Value="WideView" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="narrowView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="WrapPanel1.MaximumRowsOrColumns" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="HubSection.Header" Value="Vertical" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```